# Register Different Tasks in Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I created two kinds of tasks with Celery. One is a standalone Celery task that can do things according to database push notifications (a program listens to database and once there is a message it launches the task). Another is integrated with django that accepts a url request, which is used to fire a task. I followed [this example](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/examples/django) to setup the django app with Celery. And for the standalone Celery task, I have `tasks.py` under the outmost `django` directory (in the example) that defines the normal task:

```
from celery import Celery
from demoapp.utils.read_images import download_images_mem

app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def make_video(img_url_list, deviceid, utc, dst, cityname, streetname, CorF, lat, lon):
    download_images_mem(img_url_list, deviceid, utc, dst, cityname, streetname, CorF, lat, lon)
```

And I also have a `tasks.py` under `demoapp` directory that begins with:

```
@shared_task
def fired_by_url():
    func definitions
```

I'm using rabbitmq as the broker and redis as the backend for both tasks. My question is that how I can put them together? Basically I followed `django-celery` tutorial and a normal celery tutorial, that's why I have such weird directory layout and files. But I want to know how to put them together. I have questions like: Which celery instance should I use? The `app = Celery('proj')` in `settings.py` or `app = Celery('tasks', backend='redis://localhost', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')`? And which decorator should I use for the two tasks? How should I organize my files? They are supposed to run on the same machine. I'm really new to Celery and kind of confused at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you'll need  app=Celery('proj') in your settings.py. The other should work.